# How do I read the third value from each line of a file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm handling a loan monitoring system project, and in this project customer details will be saved in a text  file with a row for each customer like:

```
sri chennai 10000 asda casca   08989
```

From the customer details a project officer needs only the third field (that is amount of loan) and he uses that to calculate installment rate of interest which will be written to another file.

How can I extract just the needed information from the file?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question.  If you still have questions after getting an answer to this part, please post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file line by line and get the substring between second and the third space.

Please work on explaining the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BufferedReader` to read the file line by line. Use `String.split()` or `String.substring()` to locate fields. Write the result to a new file using the [IO classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) as well.